# Get a json from an external url, save it as a pdf and mail it using php

Tags: php, json, email, curl

I have successfully implemented a form where I receive a JSON base64 encoded string from an external URL using curl. After which I decode the string and save the file as a pdf using php and then email the pdf to the user's email using swiftmailer.

The main section of the code after retrieving the JSON value stream

```
$jsonvalue = $json['value'];
$dcode = (base64_decode($jsonvalue));
file_put_contents($file, $dcode); 
//Swift mailer email attachment code
```

After this I use php swiftmailer to email this file as an attachment.
Is this correct and the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

1). Not sure you can directly save the content as a .pdf file. As far I know, you need to use a thirdparty library called tcpdf http://www.tcpdf.org/ for saving the file as PDF file.

2). You can use swift mailer to send the attachment with email.

Comment: Hey Pankaj, I have already implemented the functionality. The file_put_contents function creates a new file and puts the pdf stream into it and saves it on the server. After which an email attachment goes out with the file from swift mailer. This is working. But what happens if two people try to concurrently access the file? The file is overwritten with ever new user. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: @Manatarms If its a temporary file and you dont need it after sending in attachment. Then you can generate a random hash for file name e.g. by using $fileName = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)) and read the content or attach the file to email;   There are many ways if you worry about user specific then you can append unique userid to file name then that will be unique. Let me know what exactly you want if it does not work for you.

Comment: Hey Pankaj, I found a function in swift mailer itself that builds the attachment as it's downloaded from the sever. I'm using the php uniqid() function to generate a unique filename for each attachment. Thanks for all the help. Any php performance factors that I should be worried about?